# When we compute Big-Oh for 50n logn it is O(n log n)? Can we take O(n^5) as Big-Oh?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, big-o

I recently come across some asymptotic notations and when this question arise which is 50 n logn and by popular rule to get the Big-OH  notation is to simply drop the constants and also the lower order terms.But also 50n logn is also BIG-OH of n^5.
So why the Big-oh notation is better to consider O(nlogn) rather than O(n^5).
[image: Image showing 2 graphs].

When the input size is changed as 0 to 50 in wolfram the resultant graph is here
[image]

Comment: Why do you say "50n logn is also BIG-OH of n^5"? FWIW, log(n^5) = 5*log(n), so O( log(n^5)) = O(log(n)).

Comment: try typing in `50n log n, n^5, from 0 to 50` in eg wolframalpha and you will see that for large `n`, the polynomial n^5 becomes very large relative to n log n

Comment: `O()` denotes an uper bound, `Theta()` denotes a more accurate bound.

Comment: You're perfectly right. Downvoters don't understand the concept of big-O.

Comment: Ya am i wrong in framing the question or i completely gone wrong in basic concept? @fjardon

Comment: `50n logn is also BIG-OH of n^5` Please expand what you mean by that. If you can, the question was badly framed, if you can't, you're wrong.

Comment: because when complaining about something like how low is your salary is, you prefer to say 'i don't even make enough to eat' instead of 'I can't even buy a Ferrari'

Comment: Simply put, tighter the bound better the answer. Otherwise everything is O(infinite) anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are completely right when you say that `50.n.log(n) = O(n^5)`. There is no problem with that mathematically. We can find a constant `C = 1` such that for all `n` above a certain value `10` we have

```
|50.n.log(n)| < C.|n^5|
```

See wikipedia for the [formal definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition)

There is no doubt about that.

If we prefer to say that `50.n.log(n) = O(n.log(n))` is because we often want to know what is the *slowest growing function* which dominates the complexity of the algorithm. This is commonly used to compare algorithm complexity.

Comment: @fjardon I guess this might be the real reason.I too found the same definition

Answer (score 4):

`50n log n` is not literally `O(n log n)`, and neither it is `O(n^5)`.

`50n log n` is a function.

`O(n log n)` and `O(n log n)` are both classes of functions, so `50n log n` cannot "be" either.

`50n log n` is, however, a member of *both* classes. By definition, `O(g(n))` contains all functions `f(n)` so that `∀n > N: f(n) < Mg(n)` for some constants `M` and `N`. This is (confusingly) written as `f(n) = O(g(n))`. The Big O notation describes *upper bounds on function growth*.

Two similar classes of functions in the Big-O family of notations are `Θ(n log n)` and `Θ(n^5)` (that the capital Greek letter Theta). These classes are smaller than the corresponding `O` classes. `50n log n` belongs to the first one but not to the second one. The Big Theta notation describes *tight two-sided bounds*: `f(n) = Θ(g(n))` means `f(n)` grows no faster and no slower than `g(n)` (up to some constant factor).